# Array multidimensional em Lua

Tags: lua-table

Tô tentando inserir um array dentro de uma multidimensional... Exemplo:

```
local info = {
  [1] = {name = Felipe, idade = 21, rua = Alvorada},
  [2] = {name = Carlos, idade = 23, rua = Lima},
  [3] = {name = Sabrina, idade = 19, rua = Principal}
}

local cidades = {
  ['Central'] = {info[1], info[2], info[3]}
}
```

Tentei de todas as formas até meu conhecimento, utilizei loops for and while, e não encontrei solução, onde estou errando?

---

Fiz do seguinte modo e funcionou!

```
cidades = {}
cidades['Central'] = {}
for i = 1, #info do
   cidades['Central'][i] = info[i]
end
```

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida então?